# How Vishnu created these rituals?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, identification-request

In this chapter of Brahmanda Purana says:-

> 24-29a. It was the lord who created all types of sacrifices and the necessary adjuncts thereof. He duly created the sacred fires of Gārhapatya and Āhavanīya and the monthly Śrāddha rite of Anvāhārya. He created the various adjuncts of sacrifice such as the Vedī (Altar), the Kuśa grass, the Sruvā (holy ladle), water for consecrating (Prokṣaṇīya etc.), the Śruta (holy texts and Mantras) and the Āvabhṛthya (holy water for purificatory bath at the conclusion of a sacrifice.
>
> Then he created sages who offered shares in the oblations in the fire for gods in the sacrifice (shares in the oblations). He made the Suras the partakers of Havya, and the Pitṛs the partakers of Kavya. He made persons deserving enjoyment through the holy rite of Yajña. It is the lord himself who is termed Yajña in the course of the holy performance of Yajña.
>
> He created the requisite materials of Yajña such as the Yūpas (sacrificial posts), Samits (holy twigs) Sruvā (sacred ladle), the Soma (the creeper as well as juice), the Pavitra (the sacred ring of Kuśa grass with a projecting tail) and Paridhis (the holy twigs of Palāśa etc. laid around the sacrificial fire). He created the sacrificial fires, the Sadasyas (the members of the holy assembly), the Yajamānas (performers of sacrifices), the Udgātṛs (those who sing Sāman Mantras and hymns) and others. He created excellent sacrifices such as Aśvamedha (horse sacrifices) and Rājasūya (imperial consecration) etc. of diverse kinds. By means of the Pārameṣṭhya (concerning Brahmā) holy rite he sustained the worlds and Yajñas.

But, how he created them in his any incarnations or otherwise? That information is mentioned in any other Puranas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned in detail in the *Kālikapurāṇa*

Background : In the beginning of the *kalpa*, *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu*, assuming the form of *Yajñavarāha*, emerged from the nostrils of *Prajāpati Brahmā* & lifted up *Bhūdevī*, whose  gross corporeal form on being covered with the flesh & marrow of *Madhu* & *Kaitabha* became the physical earth as we know it, hence the name of this *kalpa* is *Śvetavārāha*. (N.B *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* reappeared in this form when *Bhūdevī* was abducted by *Hiranyākṣa*). However, smitten with the arrows of *Kāma* & due to the curse of *Kapila*, *Yajñavarāha* became enamoured of *Bhūdevī* & indulged in sex with her, which resulted in the birth of 3 porcine offsprings named *Suvṛtta*, *Kaṇaka* & *Ghora* who laid waste of the cosmos. When *Bhūdevī* became pregnant for the 4th time, the *Deva*s were wary of *Yajñavarāha* & petitioned *Bhagavāna Śiva* to kill Him. Accordingly, *Bhagavāna Śiva* assumed the form of *Śarabha* & killed *Yajñavarāha* & His 3 sons. *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* disposed off *Yajñavarāha*'s corpse by creating various *yajña*s & its implements out of it.

> विदारिते वराहस्य काये भर्गेण तत्क्षणात् । ब्रह्मविष्णुशिवाः देवाः सर्वैश्च प्रमथैः सह ।। निन्युर्जलात् समुद्धृत्य तच्छरीरं नभः प्रति । तद्भिदुः शरीरं तत् विष्णोश्चक्रेण खण्डशः ।। तस्याङ्गसन्धयो यज्ञा जाताश्च वै पृथक्पृथक् । यस्मादङ्गाच्च ये जातास्तच्छृण्वन्तु महर्षयः ।।
>
> Translation: On the body of *Varāha* being immediately sliced by *Bharga*, the *deva*s *Brahmā*, *Viṣṇu*, *Śiva* accompanied by all the *pramatha*s (of *Bhagavāna Śiva*, who were created during the fight between *Yajñavarāha* & *Śarabha*) lifted it up from the waters & held it in the sky. The body was cut into pieces by the discus of *Viṣṇu*. Various *yajña*s emerged from it's limbs & joints. Hear O great sages, what arose from what limb. [*Kālikapurāṇa*:31:10-12]

> भ्रूनासासन्धितो जातो ज्योतिष्टोमो महाध्वरः । हनुश्रवणसन्धोस्तु वह्निष्टोमो व्यजायत ।। चक्षूर्भ्रूवो सन्धिना तु व्रात्यष्टोमो व्यजायत । जातः पौनर्भवष्टोमस्तस्य पोत्रौष्ठसन्धितः ।। वृद्धष्टोमवृहत्ष्टोमौ जिह्वामूलादजायताम् । अतिरात्रं सवैराजमधोजिह्वान्तरादभूत् ।। अध्यापनं ब्रह्मयज्ञः पितृयज्ञस्तु तर्पणं । होमो दैवोबलिर्भौतो नृयज्ञोऽतिथिपूजनं ।। स्नानं तर्पणपर्यन्त नित्ययज्ञाश्च सर्वशः । कण्ठसन्धेः समुत्पन्नाः जिह्वातो विधयस्तथा ।। वाजिमेधमहामेधौ नरमेधस्तथैव च । प्राणिहिंसाकरा येऽन्ते ते जाताः पादसन्धितः ।। राजसूयोऽर्थकारी च वाजपेयस्तथैव च । पृष्ठसन्धौ समुत्पन्ना ग्रहयज्ञास्तथैव च ।। प्रतिष्ठोत्सर्गयज्ञाश्च दानश्राद्धादयस्तथा । हृत्सन्धितः समुत्पन्ना सावित्रीयज्ञ एव च ।। सर्वे सांस्कारिका यज्ञाः प्रायश्चित्तकराश्च ये । ते मेढ्रसन्धितो जाताः यज्ञास्तस्य महात्मनः ।। रक्षःसत्रं सर्पसत्रं सर्वं चैवाभिचारकं । गोमेधो वृक्षयागश्च खुरेभ्योह्यभवन्निमे ।। मायेष्टिः परमेष्टिश्च गीष्पतिर्भोगसम्भवः । लाङ्गुलसन्धौ सञ्जाता अग्नीषोमस्तथैव च ।। नैमित्तिकाश्च ये यज्ञाः संक्रान्त्यादौ प्रकीर्तिताः । लाङ्गुलसन्धौ ते जातास्तथा द्वादशवार्षिकं ।। तीर्थप्रयोगसामौजः यज्ञः सङ्कर्षणस्तथा । आर्कमाथर्वणश्चैव नाड़ीसन्धेः समुद्गताः ।। ऋचोत्कर्षः क्षेत्रयज्ञाः पञ्चसर्गातियोजनः । लिङ्गसंस्थानहेरम्बयज्ञ जाताश्च जानूनि ।। एवमष्टाधिकं जातं सहस्रं द्विजसत्तमाः । यज्ञानां सततं लोका यैर्भाव्यन्तेऽधुनापि च ।।
>
> Translation: The great *yajña* named *Jyotiṣṭoma* was created from the junction of the eyebrows with the nose. *Agniṣṭoma* was created from the junction of the cheeks with the ears. *Vrātyaṣṭoma* was created from the junction of the eyes with the eyebrows. *Paunarbhavaṣṭoma* was created from the junction of the snout with the lip. *Vṛddhaṣṭoma* & *Vṛhatṣṭoma* were created from the base of the tongue. *Atirātra* & *Vairāja* were created from the lower portion of the tongue. Studying (the *Vaidika* texts belonging to one's own *śākhā*) is *brahmayajña*, doing *tarpaṇa* (in the name of deceased ancestors) is *pitṛyajña*, performing (*Aupāsana* & *Vaiśvadeva*) *homa* is *devayajña*, offering *bali* (daily to crows & dogs, occasionally to snakes) is *bhūtayajña*, serving the guest is *nṛyajña*, things done between bathing (in midday) & doing *tarpaṇa* (in the next morning) i.e offering oblation in the form of food to the hunger-fire residing in the stomach is *nityayajña*. All of these were created from the junction of the throat with the tongue. *Aśvamedha*, *Mahāmedha* (i.e *Sarvamedha*), *Naramedha* & other such *yajña*s involving animal-slaughter were created from the joints of the feet. The wealth-bestowing *Rājasūya*, *Vājapeya* & *grahayajña* were created from the joints of the back. *Yajña*s with rites of establishment (*vāstuyajña*), consecration (involved with *pūrtakarma* like planting trees, building houses, temples, forts, reservoirs, wells, fountains etc, *vṛṣotsarga*), donation (like *tulapuruṣa-dāna*, donating a thousand cows etc) & *śrāddha* (*piṇḍapitṛyajña*) and *Sāvitrīyajña* were created from the joints of the chest. *Yajña*s involved with *saṁskāra*s (like *upanayana* & marriage) & *prāyaścitta*s (like *kūṣmāṇḍa-homa* & *Nirṛtiyajña*) were created from the joints of the groin of that great soul. *Rakṣaḥsatra* (performed by *Parāśara*), *sarpasatra* (performed by *Janmejaya*) & all such *yajña*s related to sorcery, *gomedha* and *vṛkṣayāga* were created from the hooves. *Māyeṣṭi*, *Parameṣṭi*, *Gīṣpati* (i.e *Bṛhaspati-sava*), *Agniṣoma* (i.e *Sautrāmaṇi*) & other such *yajña*s that generate pleasure were created from the junction of the tail. Occasional rites performed at times like *saṁkrānti* (*darśapurṇamāsa*, *cāturmāsya*, *paśubandha*, *iśānabali*, *śulagava*, *caitrī*, *śrāvaṇī*, *āśvayujī*, *āgrahāyaṇī*, *aṣṭakā*, *pārvaṇa*) & the *yajña* having a duration of 12 years (performed by *Śaunaka*) were created from the joints of the tail. *Tīrthaprayoga*(?), *Sāmayajña*(i.e *yajña* aimed to create peace), *Ojayajña* (i.e *yajña* aimed to cure diseases), *Saṅkarṣaṇayajña*(i.e *yajña* aimed for attracting people), *Ārkayajña* (i.e *Putrakāmeṣṭiyajña*) & *Ātharvaṇayajña* (*yajña* that can be performed only by *brahmaṇa*s who practice *Atharvaveda* like coronation, invoking *kṛtyā* etc) originated from nerve-joints. *Ṛcotkarṣa*(?), *kṣetrayajña*s(?), *paṅcasarga*(?), *atiyojana*(?), *liṅgasaṁsthāna*(?) & *herambayajña* (*yajña* aimed to propitiate *Vināyaka*s as described in *Yājñavalkyasmṛti*) were created from the knees. O best amongst the *dvija*s ! In this way 1008 *yajña*s were created which continue to be practised even to this day. [*Kālikapurāṇa*:31:13-27]

> स्रुगस्य पोत्रात् सञ्जाता नासिकायाः स्रुवोऽभवत् । अन्ये स्रुक्स्रुवभेदा ये ते जाता पोत्रनासयोः ।। ग्रीवाभागेण तस्याभूत् प्राग्वंशो मुनिसत्तमाः । इष्टापूर्तिर्यजुर्धर्मो जाताः श्रवणरन्ध्रतः ।। दंष्ट्राभ्योह्यभवन् यूपाः कुशाः रोमाणि चाभवन् । उद्गाता च तथाध्वर्युर्होता शामित्रमेव च ।। अग्रदक्षिणवामाङ्गपश्चात्पादेषु सङ्गताः । पुरोडाशाः सचरवो जाता मस्तिष्कसञ्चयात् ।। कर्षूर्नेत्रद्वयाज्जाता यज्ञकेतुस्तथा क्षुरात् । मध्यभागोऽभवेद्वदी मेढ्रात् कुण्डमजायत ।। रेतोभागात्तथैवाज्यं स्वधामन्त्राः समुद्गताः । यज्ञालयः पृष्ठभागाद्हृत्पद्माद्यज्ञ एव च । तदात्मा यज्ञपुरुषो मुञ्जा कक्षात्समुद्गताः ।। एवं यावन्ति यज्ञानां भाण्डानि च हवींषि च । तानि यज्ञवराहस्य शरीरादेव चाभवन् ।।
>
> Translation: From the snout was created *sruk*, the nose became *sruva*. All other variations of *sruk* & *sruva* (i.e sacrificial ladles) originated from the snout & nose. O best amongst the sages ! From the neck was created the *prāgvaṁśa* (the room where people & materials for *yajña* are assembled). From the aperture of the ears, *iṣṭā (rite of setting up the sacred fires), pūrti* (that which is filled) & *yajurdharma*(?) were created. The teeth became the *yūpa*s (sacrificial pillars on which the sacrificial animal is to be placed), the fur became the *kuśa* grass. From the right forelimb, left forelimb, right hindlimb & left hindlimb originated the *Udgātā* (reciter of the *Sāmaveda*), *Adhvaryu* (reciter of the *Yajurveda*), *Hotā* (reciter of the *Ṛgveda*) & the pacifier (reciter of the *Atharvaveda*) respectively. From that which is stored in the head (i.e brain) originated the *puroḍāśa* & *caru*. From the 2 eyes was created the *karṣū* (holy fire fueled by cow-dung), from the hooves was created the sacrificial flags. The middle portion became the altar & the *kuṇḍa* is created from the groin. From the semen was created *ājya*, oblations & *mantra*s. From the back was created the sacrificial hall, from the lotus-like heart was created *yajña*, the soul became *yajñapuruṣa*, from the sides was created the *muñjā* (*yajñopavīta*). In this way, all the *havi*s & vessels required for *yajña* were created out of the body of *Yajñavarāha*. [*Kālikapurāṇa*:31:28-34]

The bodies of *Suvṛtta*, *Kaṇaka* & *Ghora* were transformed into *Dakṣiṇāgni*, *Gārhapatyāgni* & *Āhavanīyāgni* respectively. The 4th child of *Yajñavarāha* & *Bhūdevī*, being conceived during *Bhūdevī*'s menstrual period, turned out to have a Asuric predisposition & became *Narakāsura*.

N.B Curse of *Kapila* : According to the *Kālikapurāṇa*, sage *Kapila* asked *Manu* for some land to set up his hermitage. *Manu*, being arrogant on being appointed the lord of the entire earth, proudly remarked that he has no scarcity of land & vainly told that *Kapila* could take whatever land He wished for. *Kapila* was enraged at *Manu*'s arrogance & cursed him to witness the destruction of his realm. That curse was fulfilled by the untimely *pralaya* caused due to the fight between *Yajñavarāha* & *Śarabha* but *Manu* was saved by the *Matsya* *avatāra* of *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* & the sages who accompanied *Manu* propagated the rites of *yajña*.